# POST a string array with a key

Tags: c#

I used to send to an API with a string array:

```cs
string[] metaArray = new string[1];
metaArray[0] = "userID buyer: " + CachedUserOurself.userID;
    
var postModel = new
{
    merchant_uid = merchant_uid_toreceiveMoney,
    products = products,
    metadata = parameters,
    ...
};
```

This is working code, but will in the future not work no longer. I received this information from our API service provider:

For example, your most recent transaction defines:

```
"metadata": [
    "userID buyer: 1419"
],
```

which leads to the following key-value pairs:

```
"metadata": [
        {
            "key": "0",
            "value": "userID buyer: 1419"
        }
],
```

"key": "0", is going to lead to errors in the near future. So he will need to change the code to make sure you are sending both a key and a value. So that the result will be

```
"metadata": [
        {
            "key": "userID buyer",
            "value": "1419"
        }
],
```

So, I thought OK, I will try this:

```cs
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "userId buyer"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", CachedUserOurself.userID)
};
```

But this won't be accepted by the API.

How can I alter the array I used to send (and am still sending) so that it features a KEY?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you checked the json output? Also, has the API already updated to support this "future" format?

Comment: Did you try to serialize the `parameters` and check the JSON output? From your `parameter`, the list contains two Dictionary items but not one, and each key-value was incorrect. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FZU5iO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

```cs
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "userId buyer"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value", CachedUserOurself.userID)
};
```

This returns an array with two Key-Value pair items.

And if you serialize it, the JSON will be:

```
[
  { "Key": "key", "Value": "userId buyer" },
  { "Key": "value", "Value": /* CachedUserOurself.userID */ }
]
```

What you need is [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) which implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

The difference between `KeyValuePair` and `Dictionary` in general:

`KeyValuePair` - A single item.

`Dictionary` - Contains multiple `KeyValuePair` items.

```cs
var parameters = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "userId buyer", CachedUserOurself.userID }
    }
};
```

This results

```
[
  { "userId buyer": /* CachedUserOurself.userID */ }
]
```

For your senario,

```
var parameters = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "key", "userId buyer" },
        { "value", CachedUserOurself.userID }
    }
};
```

Result

```
[
  { "key": "userId buyer","value": /* CachedUserOurself.userID */ }
]
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7O3ZxP)

Comment: thank you! the api still refuses this, but from my console I can see that this did put it into a correct format. thank you

Comment: Nevermind, I had to not give parameters but parameter[0] to feed the api. this works! thanks!